# Rust Programming - Trying to compare user input to lines from a file

Tags: file, rust, compiler-errors, user-input

So I am trying to compare user input to the lines from a separate file name fruits.txt. I got it mostly working I believe, but I am running into this error:

```
error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'option_result_contains'
  --> src/main.rs:19:20
   |
19 |             s if s.contains(&ask) => println!("{} is a fruit!", ask),
   |                    ^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: see issue #62358 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/62358> for more information

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0658`.
error: could not compile `learn_arrays` due to previous error
```

I have tried several types of ways to match it in rust and this is the closest where it doesn't complain that I am trying to match a string to whatever type lines is. here is what it looks like

```
  use std::fs::File;
  use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead, Error, stdin};
 
  fn main() -> Result<(), Error>{
      let path = "fruits.txt";
 
      let input = File::open(path)?;
      let buffered = BufReader::new(input);
 
      let mut ask = String::new();
      stdin()
          .read_line(&mut ask)
          .expect("Failed to read line");
 
      let ask: String = ask.trim().parse().expect("Please type a valid string!");
 
      for line in buffered.lines() {
          match line {
              s if s.contains(&ask) => println!("{} is a fruit!", ask),
              _ => println!("{} is either not in the list or not a fruit", ask),
          }
      }
 
      Ok(())
 }
```

Is there a way where I can use the unstable feature or is there another better method to compare user input to lines from a file.

Comment: Your `line` inside the loop is a `io::Result<_>`. `Result` happens to have a `.contains()`-method, which is unstable. This causes confusion with `str::contains()`, which you think you are using, but are in fact not. Handle the error case, e.g. `match line { Ok(s) => ... ` to get the `String` you can call '.contains()` on.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue my changing the part where I am attempting to match the input with:

```
let mut found = false;

println!("Result");

for line in buffered.lines() {
         let s = line.unwrap();
         if s.find(&ask).is_some() {
            println!("{} is a fruit!", ask);
            found = true;
            break;
         }
     }

     if !found {
         println!("{} is either not in the list or not a fruit", ask)
     }
```